# Does Safari 15 fully support ES6?

Tags: ios, webkit

I am working on a project using Webkit.

private_class_fileds = 14.5, Private_class_Methods = 15.0, static_class_fields = 14.5
For the above JavaScript functions, I set the minimum support range for iOS to iOS 15 and conducted a test.

However, based on the Xcode iOS simulator, the web was not displayed in 15.0, 15.2, and 15.5.
It was confirmed that iOS15.6.1(iPhone7) was running on the actual terminal.

Is there a difference in the ES6 syntax available before and after version 15.6.1???